# WebSphere Portal Page Passing Parameters On Page Link Click

Tags: websphere, websphere-portal

I am using WebSphere Portal 8 and I am facing one issue related to session clearing on Portal Page link click. I have a portal page with one single portlet (Search Portlet) and it is working fine. Then after some search I navigate to another unrelated page and again click on the link to Search Portlet. The problem is previously selected values are still present in UI.

I want to know is there any way I will know which Page Link is clicked so that I can clear session in Portlet Class. Or is there anyway to pass some parameters once a Page Link is clicked.

Thanks in Advance!

Pradeep

Answer (score 0):

Portal maintains the state of the portlet, redirecting to page with clean URL will do the trick.